# 'Prompt' Equivalent in Swift

Tags: javascript, swift, prompt

I recently installed swift, hearing that it could run Javascript, but I learned it runs off 'Swift'. I have begun to learn the basics, but I have not found the equivalent to the 'Prompt' command in JS, Is there one? If so, what is it?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: What are you using swift for ? It is not meant for web development at this moment. It is for iPhone or mac app development.

Comment: I'm aware, I think. I'm trying to create a mac app, but it requires input for variables.

Comment: So your question is how you can prompt the user for input in a OSX application? You might want to remove the JavaScript references a bit then, because I'm quite sure those are attracting close votes.

Answer (score 1):

I understood that you you are creating app for mac and you need to get inputs from user. Then use GUI Controls in mac to get the required data from the user

Answer (score 0):

This is more of a Cocoa frameworks question, as you can do this with either Objective-C or Swift. For Mac apps, use the [NSAlert](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSAlert_Class/Reference/Reference.html) class. For iOS apps, use the [UIAlertView](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIAlertView_Class/index.html) class.